# Creating a function that returns a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to create a function that returns a component similar to how React Navigation does:

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Room: { screen: RoomContainer },
    Game: { 
        screen: GameContainer,
        navigationOptions: {
            gesturesEnabled: false
        }
    },
    Catalog: { screen: CatalogContainer }
}, {
        headerMode: 'none',
        mode: 'modal'
    })

Which you can then use like:

<AppNavigator />
```

I have looked at their code but still a bit confused. This is my simple example.

```
import onboardingCreator from 'this-package'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let Onboard = onboardingCreator({
      test: 'cool'
    })

    console.log("OB", Onboard)


    return (
      <Onboard />
    );
  }
}
```

And then in another file:

```
export default (props) => {
    console.log("PROPS", props)

    return <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green', flex: 1}} />
}
```

Where am I going wrong? I just need a simple example to get me in the right direction I think :)

Thanks.

Comment: Is  "this-package'" in your local file. I think you can import this `import onboardingCreator from './this-package'`. Btw a funtion return component call the "high order component". https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function is returning an *instance* of a component, not the definition of the component class.  If you want to render the instance (the way the function works now), it would look more like this:

```
import onboardingCreator from 'this-package'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let onboard = onboardingCreator({
      test: 'cool'
    })

    console.log("OB", onboard)


    return <div>{onboard}</div>;
  }
}
```

If, on the other hand, you want to create a new component and return it, it would look more like this:

```
export default (props) => {
    console.log("PROPS", props)

    class GeneratedComponent extends Component {
        render() {
            return <View
                {...props}
                style={{backgroundColor: 'green', flex: 1}}
            />;
        }
    }

    return GeneratedComponent;
}
```